# How can I post the submitted data to another page without redirecting to it #php&ajaxjqury

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello there a little help here.. How can I post a data to page(update.page.php) when I submit request form to index.php without redirecting to it. The idea for this is like submitting a message to the other page and the other page receive the message without refreshing the page.. But in this case the data from database submitted I would like to post in the update.page.php.. I would like you to help me for my thesis.. Thanks. I don't have any code for this problem, I can't show you anything.. Hope that you have a solution for this.. Ps.#apole..

Comment: I have seen a few sample in the Internet but it confuses me.. Can you give me an highlight for this a very brief code.?

Comment: Please help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should check Goolge with keyword "ajax request tutorial"

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

You should either use jquery post function something like this

`$(selector).post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)`

Option 2:
For more advance implementation implement update.page.php function as Soap API's and then post data to to that API's someThing like below

`$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/soapFunction.php?wsdl");`

`$params = array("id" => 1,"name" => "Name","description" => "Abc","amount" => 500,);`
`$response = $client->__soapCall("update", array($params));`

Answer (score 1):

> Try this example,it may help you:

```
Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function postData(){

            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update.page.php',
                data: {"firstName":fname,"lastName":lname},
                success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                    console.log('Data send');
                         //$("#display-property-address").html(data);
                }
            });
}

</script>
<form name="stable" method="POST" id="form"> 
                    <input type = 'text' name ='fname' id='fname'/>
                    <input type = 'text' name ='lname' id='lname'/>
                    <input type = 'email' name ='email' id='email'/>
                    <input type = 'button' name ='submit' value='submit' id='submit' onclick="postData()"/>
                </form>



              </body>
              </html>
```

update.page.php

```
<?php  
  $firstName= $_POST['firstName'];
  $lastName= $_POST['lastName'];

 echo "success";
 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try ajax form submission
Example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var data = 'email='+ email + '&name='+ name;
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Then I want to load the information submitted to update.page.php without refreshing the page.. How do I done that?.. By the time I submit the form, the update.page.php will automatically load the information submitted ...

Comment: I think I am not getting your question, the above code will post the data to file ajaxsubmit.php, the file will store the information in db, and your update.page.php file can retrieve the information form db? Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.. Yes, I would like to work that way.. In my script I created an online reservation. In that case there will be 2 blank tabs the other for the user/client and the other for the admin.. Here is what I want.. When user submit their request the admin page will automatically load the submitted data for confirmation of the reservation without refreshing page.. Hope that you got my idea..

Comment: Well than you can do two things one is that you can simply update the tab content through same on click function if update is static. For dynamic you can add ajax request to refresh content every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Can you please give me some codes about that.. Because I tried everything I know I've seen a few samples still i can't get the idea.. I'm just a beginner.. I have no idea how to do the script... Please help me.. Just a simple one Just to get some ideas..